# How to get class list of a tag inside a div on click of div not the tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 divs contains a tag as well as I tag as follows.i am using a on click function that doesn't indicate you have to write the function using it, use can use something like on click of this item get elements and in those elements find certain class where it is placed.

```
<div class="div" onclick="getclassofitag()">
  <a class="atag"></a>
  <i class="itag1 itag2"></i>
</div>
<div onclick="getclassofitag()">
  <a class="atag"></a>
  <i class="itag11 itag22"></i>
</div>
```

I need to get class list of  tag inside the div I clicked.
in cshtml you can use foreach for looping the div, in that case divs repeated will be having same id, same class name. so how i will be able to get the element only i clicked?
How to do it by using pure JavaScript?

the code i really have is

```
       @foreach (var j in footerPage.StaticPageFiles)
                            {
                                if (j.Type != "video")
                                {
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 files">
                                        <i class="fa fa-file " aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="@j.FilePath">@j.FileName</a>
                                    </div>
                                }

                            }
```

it will show a div with height 50px and width 100% and color red. on click of each div i want to apply some class for only the div which i clicked.

Comment: hey brianlmerritt please read the question carefully, simply dont put duplicate by reading the heading only... if you cant answer stay away...

Comment: tag means <i>,<a>,<div> .. so in this question <i class="classes">   those classes i need to find, because i need to replace that

Comment: in jquery we will use  $(this).find('.fa-chevron-down') to find the class inside the element we clicked, i need replacemnet for this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using classList property will give you the list of classes in the tag:

```
<div class="div" onclick="getclassofitag(this)">Test1
  <a class="atag"></a>
  <i class="itag1 itag2"></i>
</div>
<div onclick="getclassofitag(this)">Test2
  <a class="atag"></a>
  <i class="itag11 itag22"></i>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getclassofitag(element) {
    aTags = element.getElementsByTagName("a");
    aTagsClass = [];
    for(var i=0; i<aTags.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<aTags[i].classList.length; j++) {
            aTagsClass.push(aTags[i].classList[j]);
        }
    }


    iTags = element.getElementsByTagName("i");
    iTagsClass = [];
    for(var i=0; i<iTags.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<iTags[i].classList.length; j++) {
            iTagsClass.push(iTags[i].classList[j]);
        }
    }
    //This will give you the array of classes in `a` tag and `i` tag
    console.dir(aTagsClass);
    console.dir(iTagsClass);
}
</script>
```

Comment: shwetha, it will only take the clicked item ryt?

Comment: Yes, you will get the clicked DIV's <a> and <i> tag's classes.. you have mentioned in your question that u need the clicked DIV's <i> and <a> tags class list right?

Comment: Don't vote down, let me know what exactly you want

Comment: no way... ur good only.... i  need onmore help. how can i toggle one of the class in that i tag? can you tell?.. i mean instead of  logging class list how can i toggle of the class in that list.

Comment: Thanks for the vote up. You can use  iTags[0].classList.toggle('itag1'); this will toggle 'itag1' class of the i tag.

Comment: toggle means i have to toggle between two classe right? but here you are mentioning only on class. what if i wnat toglle between classes itag1 and newitag1?

Comment: Toggle means add the class if it doesn't exist and remove the class if it exists. In your case, you have to add only one class to that element in html. <i class="itag1"></i>. And then user JS to toggle iTags[0].classList.toggle('itag1'); iTags[0].classList.toggle('itag2'); This will toggle between 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

It may help,

```
var c = element.childNodes; //get element from click event
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    console.log(c[i].nodeName) //You will get child tags <i> & <a> 
}
```

Add user class(which have styles to display in red color) to c[i].nodeName